# Can XorShift return zero?

Tags: c++, random

I've been reading about the XorShift PRNG especially the paper [here](http://vigna.di.unimi.it/ftp/papers/xorshift.pdf)

A guy [here](https://forum.mikrotik.com/viewtopic.php?t=100868) states that

> The number lies in the range [1, 2**64).  Note that it will NEVER be 0.

Looking at the code that makes sense:

```
uint64_t x;
uint64_t next(void) {
   x ^= x >> 12; // a
   x ^= x << 25; // b
   x ^= x >> 27; // c
   return x * UINT64_C(2685821657736338717);
}
```

If `x` would be zero than every next number would be zero too. But wouldn't that make it less useful? The usual use-pattern would be something like `min + rand() % (max - min)` or converting the 64 bits to 32 bits if you only need an `int`. But if `0` is never returned than that might be a serious problem. Also the bits are not `0` or `1` with the same probability as obviously `0` is missing so zeroes or slightly less likely. I even can't find any mention of that on Wikipedia so am I missing something?

So what is a good/appropriate way to generate random, equally distributed numbers from XorShift64* in a given range?

Comment: Just subtract 1 from it if you need to allow 0. `uint64_t rand() {return xorshift_next() - 1;}`

Comment: Using modulus is not appropriate for getting uniform random numbers with *any* base PRNG.

Comment: I know about the modulus issue (first `n` values will be more likely) but it is the easiest/fastest solution. Given that it might be enough to subtract one. I'd still be interested in a more general solution as someone must have come across this already. Or is it just some kind of rejection sampling that is then used?

Comment: Yes generally just combine with rejection sampling.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No it cannot return zero.

According the [Numeric Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/empanel/index.html#pg=345) "it produces a full period of `2^64-1` [...] the missing value is zero".

The essence is that those shift values have been chosen carefully to make very long sequences (full possible one w/o zero) and hence one can be sure that every number is produced. Zero is indeed the fixpoint of this generator, hence it produces 2 sequences: Zero and the other containing every other number.

So IMO for a sufficiently small range `max-min` it is enough to make a function `(next() - 1) % (max - min) + min` or even omitting the subtraction altogether as zero will be returned by the modulo.
If one wants better quality equal distribution one should use the 'usual' method by using `next()` as a base generator with a range of `[1, 2^64)`

Answer (score 0):

I am nearly sure that there is an `x`, for which the xorshift operation returns 0.

Proof:

First, we have these equations:

```
a = x ^ (x >> 12);
b = a ^ (a << 25);
c = b ^ (b >> 27);
```

Substituting them:

```
b = (x ^ x >> 12) ^ ((x ^ x >> 12) << 25);

c = b ^ (b >> 27) = ((x ^ x >> 12) ^ ((x ^ x >> 12) << 25)) ^ (((x ^ x >> 12) ^ ((x ^ x >> 12) << 25)) >> 27);
```

As you can see, although `c` is a complex equation, it is perfectly abelian.

It means, you can express the bits of `c` as fully boolean expressions of the bits of `x`.

Thus, you can simply construct an equation system for the bits `b0`, `b1`, `b2`, ... so:

(Note: the coefficients are only examples, I didn't calculate them, but so would it look):

```
c0 = x1 ^ !x32 ^ x47 ...
c1 = x23 ^ x45 ^ !x61 ...
...
c63 = !x13 ^ ...
```

From that point, you have 64 equations and 64 unknowns. You can simply solve it with [Gauss-elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), you will always have a single unique solution.

Except some rare cases, i.e. if the determinant of the coefficients of the equation system is zero, but it is very unlikely in the size of such a big matrix.

Even if it happens, it would mean that *you have an information loss in every iteration*, i.e. you can't get all of the `2^64` possible values of `x`, only some of them.

Now consider the much more probable possibility, that the coefficient matrix is non-zero. In this case, for all the possible `2^64` values of `x`, you have all possible `2^64` values of `c`, and these are all different.

Thus, you *can* get zero.

*Extension:* actually you get zero for zero... sorry, the proof is more useful to show that it is not so simple as it seems for the first spot. The important part is that you can express the bits of `c` as a boolean function of the bits of `x`.

---

There is another problem with this random number generator. And this is that even if you somehow modify the function to *not* have such problem (for example, by adding 1 in every iteration):

1. You still can't guarantee that it won't get into a short loop *for any possible values of `x`. What if there is a 5 length loop for value 345234523452345? Can you prove for all possible initial values? I can't.
2. Actually, having a *really* pseudorandom iteration function, your system will likely loop after `2^32` iterations. It has a nearly trivial combinatoric reason, but "unfortunately this margin is small to contain it" ;-)

So:

- If a `2^32` loop length is for your PRNG okay, then use a proven iteration function collected from somewhere on the net.
- If it isn't, upgrade the bit length to at least `2^128`. It will result a roughly `2^64` loop length which is not so bad.
- If you still want a 64-bit output, then use 128-bit numeric internally, but return `(x>>64) ^ (x&(2^64-1))` (i.e. xor-ing the upper and lower half of the internal state `x`).

Comment: I still doubt it. If x could get zero at some point you'd have a fix point. From that point on it will never return anything but zero which would make it unsuitable as a PRNG. And beeing a PRNG you would even be unable to tell when this would happen.

Comment: Unless it is a very poorly constructed PRNG, this (either reaching zero or entering a short cycle) should never happen, as it would render it essentially useless.

Comment: "I am nearly sure that there is an x, for which the xorshift operation returns 0." - yeah, but that x is 0. Unless you start at 0, you'll never reach 0.

Comment: @user2357112 Right, I overcomplicated it :-) I would be sorry to simply delete the whole proof, particularly that it first part could be useful, so I extended a note into the post.